# How do i randomize an Ordered List using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a test that contains questions.

I want the questions to come up on the page randomized rather than in an ordered list.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ol id = "questionList">
<li id="question">Question text<br/></li>
<li id="question">Question text<br/></li>
</ol>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var questionsList = document.getElementById('question');
var questionArray=[];
var randomize;

for (var i=0; questionsList.length>0; i++) {
        questionArray[i]=questionList[i];
}
randomize = questionArray.Math.random()*questionList.length;

document.getElementById("questionsList").innerHTML= randomize;
```

I cant figure out how to get the questions to appear randomly rather than from #1 down to #10.

Any  help is appreciated.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has already been asked ([How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array))

But here's the basics:

A solid shuffle algorithm is the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle.

See https://github.com/coolaj86/knuth-shuffle

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var arr = ["question 1", "question 2"];
shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```